# Selenium Webdriver(Java) - crop string value from array

Tags: java, arrays, selenium

I have an array with values as:

**(C:), (D:), (E:)**  -  I need to crop any of this value to get - **C , D or E**

The array is :

```
WebElement table =  new WebDriverWait(Login.driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                (By.id("table1")));

List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.id("td1"));
java.util.Iterator<WebElement> i = rows.iterator();

while(i.hasNext()) {
   WebElement row = i.next();
   cont = row.getText();
   System.out.println("Test1: "+cont);
}
```

I have tried to use

```
    String[] v_split = cont.split(" ");
    String v_splCmpIc = v_split[0];
```

But this shown an array index.

Is there any chance to crop an index as I showed above?

Comment: I have put inside : while(i.hasNext()) {
            WebElement row = i.next();
            cont = row.getText().replace("","(");
            System.out.println("Test1 "+cont);
        } , but the results are : Test1 (((C(:()(
Test1 (((E(:()(
Test1 (((G(:()(

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be :

```
cont = row.getText().replace("(","").replace(")","").replace(":","");  // inside while
```

Answer (score 0):

If value of string "count" is fixed length you. You can make use of `substring()` method.
You can see more details and samples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)